# Remove Classes from Menu

Tags: routes, theming

I know that this isn't a really big priority but with the default Drupal menu you get css classes like `.first` or `.last` or `.active`.

`.first` and `.last` are being provided by CSS3 and `.active` only needs to be on the `<a>` link not on the `<li>` due to the way my CSS works.

All these classes are unneeded and I'd like to remove them, so I can create a clean and efficient template.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this (and if possible provide a small code sample)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're going to have to alter you're theme to provide an alternate function to provide an entry point into menu_tree_output. This means finding the block or function that renders the menu, overriding that function, and each that it calls until you get to menu_tree_output.

After that copy a changed version of menu_tree_output into your theme's template.php and modify it as necessary. You may even have to override theme_menu_link to prevent options from showing up on both the li and a elements.

For the most part though, I think you answered your own question at:

> only needs to be on the 'a' link not on the 'li' due to the way my CSS works.

Obviously, a CMS cannot readily accomodate the needs of all possible combinations of CSS. I often have to add classes due to the complex needs of the navigation for crazy designs. I would count myself lucky if I didn't have to add classes, and just had extra classes available in the markup.

Answer (score 3):

if you wanna kill off all the classes that comes out with the menu list 
look after the theme_menu_link() thats where the

```
<li class="first leaf menu-mlid-305">
```

comes from

if you really wanna kill all the classes you can do something like this :

```
function THEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  //unset all the classes
  unset($variables['element']['#attributes']['class']);

  $element = $variables['element'];

  if($variables['element']['#attributes'])

  $sub_menu = '';


  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

dump that dunction into you template.php and you the classes that the menus comes with will go kaboom - you will also remove the active classes etc, but hey the li tags are goddamn clean

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you render the menu.

If the menu is rendered via [menu_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7), you can strip all classes from menu tree like that:

**Solution 1**  template_preprocess_menu_link():

```
function MYMODULE_OR_THEME_preprocess_menu_link(array &$variables) {
  // Unset all the classes.
  unset($variables['element']['#attributes']['class']);
}
```

**Solution 2**  [theme_menu_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7):

```
function MYTHEME_menu_tree($variables) {
  // Strip all classes from menu tree.
  $variables['tree'] = preg_replace('/class="[^"]*"/i', '', $variables['tree']);
  return '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

You can do the same with `MYTHEME_preprocess_menu_tree()`.

**Solution 3** [theme_menu_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) as @mortendk suggested.